# SQL server convert int field to bit

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a big database and I should to normalize it. One of the table contains field with type "integer" but it contains only 1 and 0 values. So it is good reason to convert this field to bit type. But when I try to save changes in SQL Server Management Studio it tells me that I can't do it. Also I have many field with values like *nvarchar* that should be converted to int or float that should be converted to int too.

Moreover I should create migration scripts for all changes so I can update real database without loosing data. Maybe somebody knows useful utility for this?

**EDIT:** It tells me that I can't update unable without drop it. And I want to update table without losing any data.

SQL version 2014

Comment: I would hope SQL Server management studio gives you a bit more indication than  simply you "can't do it"... What is the exact error? What version of SQL Server are you using? If you are using 2012+ you could use `TRY_CONVERT` to identify the problem rows - `SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE TRY_CONVERT(BIT, YourColumn) IS NULL AND YourColumn IS NOT NULL;`

Comment: Does it really tell  you "You can't do it"? Or does it provide a reason?

Comment: Your last sentence will cause your question to be claused as off-topic because you are asking for an off-site resource. Show what you have tried and what issues you had so that we can try to fix it.

Comment: I believe the error must be because it won't convert the whole populated column 'on the fly'? You ought to add a new bit column, migrate the data to it, drop the old column and then rename this new one if needed.

If the error is not the mentioned one, you should add more info to your question.

Comment: @MK_ maybe you know some program to simplify this work?

Answer (score 3):

```
    ---Create one Temp. Column
    Alter Table [dbo].[Demo2]
    Add tempId int

    GO

    --Copy Data in temp. Coulmn
    Update [dbo].[Demo2] set tempId=Id


    --Drop column which you want to modify
    Alter Table [dbo].[Demo2]
    Drop Column Id
    Go

    --Create again that column with bit type
    Alter Table [dbo].[Demo2]
    Add Id bit
    GO
    --copy date back
    Update [dbo].[Demo2] set Id=tempId

    --drop temp column
    Alter Table [dbo].[Demo2]
    Drop Column tempId

    Go
```

Comment: yes, this is great solution, but I have about 300 tables and each contains about 2-3 unnormalized fields. This is going to be very long to od everything manually. I read about "Ent.Manager". It does same work as you wrote in few clicks. But I can't find this program

Comment: @dantey89 making changes to 300 tables is not something that I would take lightly! if you wanted to do this across the board in one go I suggest looking at using `dynamic sql` to populate the changes and iterate through the tables you want to change

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to add a new column to a table, set that column to the old column and then remove the old column

```
CREATE TABLE #test
(inttest int

)

Insert [#test]
        ( [inttest] )
Values  ( 0  
          )


Insert [#test]
        ( [inttest] )
Values  ( 1  
          )

Alter Table [#test] Add bittest bit

Update [#test] Set bittest=inttest

Alter Table [#test] Drop Column [inttest]

SELECT * FROM [#test] [T]
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate migration script you don't need a special utility, SSMS does it pretty well.

Right-click the table in SSMS object explorer. Choose `Design` item in the context menu. Change the type of the column. In the main menu `Table Designer` choose item `Generate Change Script`. Save the generated script to a file, review it and make sure you understand each line in it before you run it on a production system. Adjust the script if needed.

---

On the other hand, to change the column type from `int` to `bit` you can use the [`ALTER TABLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) statement:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName
ALTER COLUMN ColumnName bit NOT NULL
```

Before running this you should check that actual `int` values are indeed only 0 and 1.

Comment: I did it like this but it shows me that I can't do it cause don't permitted to drop and recreate table

Comment: 1) It is always a good idea to include an exact error message that you are getting in your question. 2) You need to log in as a user that has these permissions to make such changes. 3) A third-party utility won't help here.

Comment: The problem that I can't do it anyway. I should keep all data in safe

Answer (score 0):

After reading of all comments and posts I found solution in building procedure which will convert passed table and column in required. So I wrote this function

```
IF EXISTS (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'IntToBit') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1)
DROP PROCEDURE IntToBit
GO


IF OBJECT_ID('convertion_table', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.convertion_table;
go

CREATE  TABLE dbo.convertion_table
(
    bitTypeColumn bit NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    intTypeColumnt integer ,
)
go

CREATE procedure IntToBit
@table nvarchar(150),
@column nvarchar(150)

AS
begin

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
SELECT @sql ='
    --copy data to temp table
    INSERT INTO convertion_table (bitTypeColumn)
    SELECT '+@column +'
    FROM ' +@table+'

    --Drop column which you want to modify
    Alter Table ' +@table+'
    Drop Column '+@column +'


    --Create again that column with bit type
    Alter Table ' +@table+'
    Add '+@column +' bit NOT NULL DEFAULT(0)

     --copy date back
    INSERT INTO '+@table+'('+@column+')
    SELECT bitTypeColumn
    FROM convertion_table

    --cleare temp table
    --DELETE bitTypeColumn FROM convertion_table 
    '
    exec sp_executesql @sql
end
GO
```

and then call it passing field and table name :

```
exec dbo.IntToBit @table = 'tbl_SystemUsers', @column='intUseLogin';
```

Special thanks to **Chris K** and **Hitesh Thakor**

Answer (score 0):

Simply Use TSql script to modify the table rather than using the designer

```
ALTER TABLE YourTableNameHere
ALTER COLUMN YourColumnNameHere INT
```

If you are using sql Server then you might wanna generate script for the table before altering the table so that you dont loose any data ..and you can simply retrieve everything using the script